# python - Gtk.Settings' default font is wrong

Tags: python, fonts, gtk, pygtk

I'm developing a Python3 GTK app.

When I put a label on the window, it doesn't use the default font of system.

The default font is 'Ubuntu' but it uses a font called 'Cantarell'.
[image: Python's output vs glade-preview]

**(Left is `python3 main.py`, Right is `glade-previewer`)**

---

I printed the default settings:

```py
print(Gtk.Settings.get_default().get_property("gtk-font-name"))
# Cantarell 11
```

Here is how I imported the gtk:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gio, Gtk
```

Why? How can I solve this? How can I make it use the system's default font? Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce your behavior (debian LXDE). Tell, which Window Manager?

Comment: Gnome, Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: But it is about python I think isn't it? I wrote the same application with Vala Language and it seems exactly like glade-previewer, but python gtk library isn't using the system's default font. Actually that is the point. The font you set on gnome-tweaks should be applied globally on GTK based applications.

Summary: I think I shouldn't write an extra code to get default font of system, but GTK components should come with default font. (Because in C and Vala, it works like this)

Comment: ***"But it is about python gtk"***: Maybe, your explanation makes sense. I got your point, even i can't reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH I FIGURED IT OUT.

When I run `python3 main.py` on Visual Studio Code's terminal, the app's default font is `Cantarell 11`

When I run `python3 main.py` from gnome-terminal, the default font is `Ubuntu 11`

So the problem isn't about python...

Solved when I run it from normal terminal app.